# I'm stuck on drawing a bezier curve in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

https://i.snag.gy/iQUyxz.jpg

I'm working on windows application form in VS 2017. The requirement is to draw a bezier curve by using three input numbers like (56, 150, 400).

I'm really confused as how to draw this.

```
Private Sub DrawCurve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DrawCurve.Click
    Try
        'Declared myColor earlier
        Dim color = myColor
        Dim myPen As Pen = New Pen(myColor, 8)
        Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim pt1 As Point = New Point(CInt(curvePT1.Text),CInt(curvePT1.Text))
        Dim pt2 As Point = New Point(CInt(curvePT2.Text),CInt(curvePT2.Text))
        Dim pt3 As Point = New Point(CInt(curvePT2.Text),CInt(curvePT2.Text))
        Dim curvedPoints As Point() = {pt1, pt2, pt3}
        'Draw Bezier Curve
        CreateGraphics().Clear(Form.ActiveForm.BackColor)
        myGraphics.DrawBezier(myPen, curvedPoints)
    Catch
        MsgBox("Please enter numerical value!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this code but the bezier curve in visual basic requires 4 points. With four points it's working fine. Maybe I'm not getting the requirement as shown in the picture, because I never studies bezier curve.

Comment: Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics 
  |    myGraphics.DrawBezier(myPen, New Point(56, 150), New Point(150, 300), New Point(300, 400))

Comment: And have you spent any time researching Bezier curves now? Without looking into it specifically, I doubt that it's possible with three points because there would be too many different curves that would pass through those same three points.

Comment: Don't put your code in a comment. Put it in the question and format it appropriately.

Comment: The relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve#Specific_cases) refers to quadratic and cubic Bezier curves but, the .NET `DrawBezier` method apparently only does the cubic ones. There is a `DrawCurve` method that will work with three points.

Comment: Please click this link to see the desired output from the given input of (56, 150, 400)

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: Why are you posting a link that you already have in your question?  Please use a bit of common sense when posting questions and comments.

Comment: As for your code, don't EVER call `CreatGraphics` and especially don't call it twice. If you ever do create a disposable object though, make sure that you dispose it.  If you want to draw using GDI+ and you want to draw on a control rather than on an image, handle the `Paint` event and use the `Graphics` object provided.

Comment: `DrawBezier` requires four points. That's not going to change no matter how much you want it to so, if you don't have four points, you can't call `DrawBezier`. You should be consulting the documentation yourself to find this out for yourself but, as far as I can see, `DrawCurve` is the only method that will draw a curve based on three points so experimenting with that seems the obvious next step.

Comment: Your reference to wikipedia page turned out to be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Consider what @jmcilhinney said about `CreateGraphics`. This is very important. You must use the a Control's `Paint()` event's `PaintEventArgs` `Graphics` object to draw your shapes. You'll find out why soon enough (read the Docs, anyway). I suggest to use the [GraphicsPath.AddBeziers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addbeziers) method to draw the Beziers curves. After you add the Points required to describe the Bezier, you can then inspect the `GraphicsPath` object and see how the splines have been constructed: what control points are created.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a spline through three points doesn't produce the same result as drawing a cubic Bezier curve. A spline curve tends to have sharper bends (think of a wire coathanger).

Actually the .Net framework does include quadratic Beziers: the QuadraticBezierSegment in WPF. With suitable references, it wouldn't be hard to make a function to use it in a System.Drawing context.

But it's even easier to draw a quadratic Bezier curve using plain arithmetic. You start by choosing the number of points to plot - 5 points might be enough, or more if you want a smoother result. Here's a function (plus 2 supporting functions) which, given 3 control points and the number of points you want to plot, returns a list of PointFs representing the quadratic Bezier:

```
        Public Function QuadraticBezier(controlPoint1 As PointF, controlPoint2 As PointF, 
controlPoint3 As PointF, numberOfPoints As Integer) As PointF()

          Dim lst As New List(Of PointF)
          For t As Double = 0 To 1 Step 1 / (numberOfPoints - 1)
             lst.Add(QuadBezierPoint(controlPoint1, controlPoint2, controlPoint3, t))
          Next
          Return lst.ToArray

       End Function

       Private Function QuadBezierPoint(p1 As PointF, p2 As PointF, p3 As PointF, t As Double) 
As PointF

          Dim q1 As PointF = LinearInterpolate(p1, p2, t)
          Dim q2 As PointF = LinearInterpolate(p2, p3, t)
          Return LinearInterpolate(q1, q2, t)

       End Function

       Private Function LinearInterpolate(p1 As PointF, p2 As PointF, t As Double) 
As PointF

          Dim x As Double = p1.X + (p2.X - p1.X) * t
          Dim y As Double = p1.Y + (p2.Y - p1.Y) * t
          Return New PointF(CSng(x), CSng(y))

       End Function
```

Once you have the points, you can draw the curve however you like, for example using Graphics.DrawCurve or as straight lines. Even with just 5 points, it will look a lot more like a Bezier than drawing through just 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

Afterthought. The simplest possible answer to the original question is just to duplicate one of the available points. For example p2 as here:

```
    Dim curvedPoints As Point() = {pt1, pt2, pt2, pt3}
    '.... 
    'Draw Bezier Curve
    myGraphics.DrawBezier(myPen, curvedPoints)
```

The result won't be the same as a quadratic Bezier, because the doubled point 'pulls' harder on the curve. But it will still be a Bezier curve.

BB